# Coloring a box according to the difficulty of the task in examclass and xcolorbox

Tags: color, exam

I am trying for a couple of hours to achieve sth. like this coloring task by its difficulty level[image]

Trying a lot searching documentation of examclass and xcolor but I couldn't find anything which can help. Chat GPT suggested two ways, but far away from desired result. Namely:

```
  \ifnum#1=1
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{-2pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{4pt}%
    \colorbox{easy}{\textcolor{white}{#2}}%
  \else
    \ifnum#1=2
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{-2pt}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
      \colorbox{medium}{\textcolor{black}{#2}}%
    \else
      \ifnum#1=3
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{-2pt}%
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
        \colorbox{hard}{\textcolor{white}{#2}}%
      \else
        #2%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

Can anybody help me?